# How to style the first paragraph of a section in HTML5?

Tags: css, html

In books and printed documents, the first paragraph of a chapter or section has one special property. While all paragraphs have an indent, the first paragraph of a section doesn't have, while the first letter of a chapter might be bolder or larger.

I want to ask, is there a default or native HTML5 way to mark a paragraph as the first of a section/chapter, to which special properties are applied? If not, which is an efficient way to mark the first paragraph?

What I have done so far, is defining properties to the `<p>` tag in the `<style>` section, giving it some indent, and creating a new property named `<p1>` with 0 indent, which I use for first paragraphs. However there is no way to change the heading/first capital letter, and I wonder if there are better ideas.

Comment: `<p1>` — That isn't a paragraph. That's a made-up tag that is not HTML and will not be recognized as a paragraph. Screen readers won't treat it as a paragraph. Search engines don't treat it as a paragraph. If you can't distinguish the elements you want from their context, give them a class or id.

Answer (score 3):

You just make it the first paragraph in a section element.

```css
section > p:first-of-type {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Section heading</h2>
  <p>First paragraph</p>
  <p>Second paragraph</p>
  <p>Third paragraph</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

For styling the first letter of a paragraph, CSS provides the [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) [`::first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter). Following Quentin's example, you could style the first letter of the first paragraph of a section like:

```
section > p:first-of-type::first-letter {
     font-family: serif;
     color: red;
     font-size: 3.75em;
     font-style: oblique;
     float: left;
     line-height: 3.5rem;
}
```

Here's a working example of both of our suggestions tied together:

https://jsfiddle.net/q51o5xqx/2/

You also mention "giving it some indent". Do you mean you want the first paragraph to have a smaller width from the other paragraphs, or do you mean you want the first line of each paragraph to be indented?

If you want a paragraph to be indented, you can simply use [`text-indent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent). By default, it will only indent the first line of a block of text, not every line of that paragraph. So something like:

```
section > p {
   text-indent: 3em;
}
```